# First value in drop down option should be disabled - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have dropdown list which has the following options

```
  ---select an option---
  option 1
  option 2
  option 3
  option 4
```

I want to disable my 1st value ---Select an option--- in dropdown list. So that it could not be selected as an option.

My code is here

```
<%= f.select :options, options_for_select([[" ---Select an option---", ""], "option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"]), :style => "margin:20px; width:356px;" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby it looks like this:

```
<%= f.select options_for_select(["", "Please select", "option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"], :disabled => "Please select", :selected => "Please select") %>
```

Would be good to assign a class to the select tag and move the styles to your styling files

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working. But I needed to remove "" from  options.

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
<%= f.select :options, [[" ---Select an option---", ""], "option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"], {}, :style => "margin:20px; width:356px;" %>
```

also, it's better to give it a css `class` and then add margin/width/etc to the class rather than in the code.  (**edit** - when i say 'better', i just mean a better practice - if you want to use this same formatting again you can just add the class and if you want to modify how it looks you just modify the one class - it won't change how it preforms, it just makes your code easier to work with.)

One way you can do that is with `span`:

```
<span class="options_select">
  <%= f.select :options, [[" ---Select an option---", ""], "option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"], {} %>
</span>
```

Comment: are you getting an error, or it's just not doing what you want?

Comment: The 2nd idea also not working. I think the class wont make any problem- @dax

Comment: I ve added my complete code previously without missing anything. only the options in dropdown are renamed. @dax

Comment: see update i made - also, what is the `{}` at the end for?  Try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: I implemeented the above too. no use

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37117/discussion-between-dax-and-jsd)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need to set your first option disable but selected true.
So it will select first option only at first time then user can't select that.

i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function favBrowser()
{
var mylist=document.getElementById("myList");
document.getElementById("favorite").value=mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
Select your favorite browser:
<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select Browser</option>
  <option>Google Chrome</option>
  <option>Firefox</option>  
  <option>Internet Explorer</option>
  <option>Safari</option>
  <option>Opera</option>
</select>
<p>Your favorite browser is: <input type="text" id="favorite" size="20"></p>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this will help you..